# Counting items in each category - php loop on xml categorized list

Tags: php, xml

I have a new problem in xml looping on xml nodes, where each group of items are wrapped with category node,
what i want to do is:
1- get randomly 3 items from any of the categories "randomly".
2- get the parent of each of the selected items.

my XML sample and php are in the below eval or as written below:
https://eval.in/544360

```
<?php
$x = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List>
<category name="cat1" dispName="First Category" catCode="FC1">
    <item itmCode="item1" show="true">
        <name>item 1</name>
        <img>path to image 1</img>
    </item>
    <item itmCode="item2">
        <name>item 2</name>
        <img>path to image 2</img>
    </item>
</category>
<category name="cat2" dispName="Second Category" catCode="SC2">
    <item itmCode="item21">
        <name>item 21</name>
        <img>path to image 21</img>
    </item>
    <item itmCode="item22">
        <name>item 22</name>
        <img>path to image 22</img>
    </item>
    <item itmCode="item54">
        <name>item 54</name>
        <img>path to image 54</img>
    </item>
    <item itmCode="item99">
        <name>item 99</name>
        <img>path to image 99</img>
    </item>
</category>
</List>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$itemCount=0;
foreach($xml->category->item as $item){
  $itemCount++;
}
echo $itemCount;?>
```

Thanks a lot for any help and support

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display random elements from XML in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780231/display-random-elements-from-xml-in-php)

Comment: the problem is not just the random selection, but its getting all items of all available categories and randomly get x items from the fetched items list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating the first `<category>` only, it has two `<item>` nodes.
To accomplish your outcomes, I suggest to...

- use `xpath()` to get an array `$items` of **all** `<item>` nodes in your XML.
- randomize `$items` with `shuffle()`
- iterate over `$items` array and echo each `<item>`
- use `xpath()` again to get the `<item>`'s parent and echo its `name`-attribute
- `break` the loop after 3 iterations

sample code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$items = $xml->xpath("/List/category/item");
shuffle($items);

$count = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item->name . " from category ";
    echo $item->xpath("../@name")[0] . PHP_EOL;

    $count++;
    if ($count >= 3) break;    
}
```

see it in action: https://eval.in/545896

Comments:

- `xpath()` returns an array of `SimpleXml`-elements, that's why each `$item`can be treated as an object (`echo $item->name;`).
- and `xpath()`can be used again to retrieve the parent (`..`) and its attribute (`../@name`); note that `@` for attribute.
- because `xpath()` returns an array, it needs to be de-referenced with `[0]` (2nd `echo`).

Update:

On PHP < 5.4 you should update, and if this is not possible, de-reference like this:

```
$parents = $item->xpath('../@name'); 
echo $parents[0] . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer, as am moving very smoothly in the steps you mentioned but on my server i got the below parse error:  <br/>  

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'**  <br/>  
the issue is to be referring on the below line :'(  <br/>  
  
'echo $item->xpath("../@name")[0] . PHP_EOL;'

Comment: @ShahirMorgan Php Version?

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.17

Comment: godaddy linux server

Comment: I Got it :)
  `$parent=$item->xpath('../@name');`
  `echo $parent[0].PHP_EOL;`  Really don't know how to thank you for your support as you lead me to the solution (Y)